# add two columns in dataframe on basis of column names

Tags: r

Example: I have a data frame

```
> a = data.frame(T_a_1=c(1,2,3,4,5),T_a_2=c(2,3,4,5,6),T_b_1=c(3,4,5,6,7),T_c_1=c(4,5,6,7,8),length=c(1,2,3,4,5))
> a    
T_a_1 T_a_2 T_b_1 T_c_1 length
1     2     3     4      1
2     3     4     5      2
3     4     5     6      3
4     5     6     7      4
5     6     7     8      5
```

I want to add( or do some other operation like (column1+column2)/length on columns on the basis of names.
Like T_a (T_a_1 and T_a_2) is common name between two columns (1st and 2nd), so I would like to add them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `grep` command for the job to match column names against some pattern. Here are some examples:

```
> a = data.frame(T_a_1=c(1,2,3,4,5),
+                T_a_2=c(2,3,4,5,6),
+                T_b_1=c(3,4,5,6,7),
+                T_c_1=c(4,5,6,7,8),
+                length=c(1,2,3,4,5))
> 
> # display only columns that match T_a
> a[,grep('T_a', colnames(a))]
  T_a_1 T_a_2
1     1     2
2     2     3
3     3     4
4     4     5
5     5     6
> 
> # sum
> sum(a[,grep('T_a', colnames(a))])
[1] 35
> 
> #rowsum
> rowSums(a[,grep('T_a', colnames(a))])
[1]  3  5  7  9 11
> 
> # your example (row1 + row2) / length
> rowSums(a[,grep('T_a', colnames(a))]) / a$length
[1] 3.000000 2.500000 2.333333 2.250000 2.200000
```

UPDATE:

From the comments below, I understand that you want to sum the matching rows grouped by common prefix and divide by length column. The following code is an inelegant solution for the problem:

```
> a = data.frame(ES51_223_1=c(1,2,3,4,5),
+                ES51_312_1=c(2,3,4,5,6),
+                ES52_223_2=c(3,4,5,6,7),
+                ES52_312_2=c(4,5,6,7,8),
+                ES53_223_3=c(1,2,3,4,5),
+                length=c(1,2,3,4,5))
> 
> # get the unique prefixes
> prefixes = unique(unlist(lapply(colnames(subset(a, select=-length)), function(x) { strsplit(x, '_')[[1]][[1]]})))
> 
> f = function(prefix) {
+   return (rowSums(subset(a, select=grep(prefix, colnames(a)))) / a$length)
+ }
> m = matrix(unlist(lapply(prefixes, f)), nrow=nrow(a))
> colnames(m) = prefixes
> m
         ES51     ES52 ES53
[1,] 3.000000 7.000000    1
[2,] 2.500000 4.500000    1
[3,] 2.333333 3.666667    1
[4,] 2.250000 3.250000    1
[5,] 2.200000 3.000000    1
```

`m` is the matrix that contains the results for different prefixes in different columns.

Comment: Thanks. But I dont know before hand the pattern. All I know that there would be "*_*". Was trying to use strsplit using lapply, but I have no clue what I am doing with them

Comment: @user1631306, What **exactly** is the format of your columns?

Comment: They are "ES51_223_1 ES51_312_1 ES52_223_2 ES52_312_2 ES53_223_3". So, I would be considering first part before "_"

Comment: Ok, but what computations you need to do depending on the prefix of the column name? Because you can match those names with regular expressions easily.

Comment: If the prefix matches, I would have to just calculate the sum of two columns divided by values in another column(length).. Computations part for individual columns I have done in one line using lapply.. EX- tranNorm<-apply(data[,c(2:18)],2,function(x) x/as.numeric(data$transcriptLength) ) ... but Dont know how to do it using pattern matching

Comment: For `ES53` there's only 1 column. what's the second column?

Comment: There are at most two columns having same prefix. Some columns like ES53, doesnt have another columns with same prefix

Comment: And what do you want to do for those columns?

Comment: those columns would ve divided by length only. So if multiple columns are there,,there average woulf be divided by length else,,,single column will be divided by length

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
# data
df <- structure(list(ES51_223_1 = 1:5, ES51_312_1 = 2:6, ES52_223_2 = 3:7, 
      ES52_312_2 = 4:8, ES53_223_3 = 1:5, length = 1:5), 
      .Names = c("ES51_223_1", "ES51_312_1", "ES52_223_2", "ES52_312_2", 
      "ES53_223_3", "length"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")

# create indices from factor levels (shortcut)
ids <- gsub("_.*$", "", setdiff(names(df), "length"))
ids <- factor(as.numeric(factor(ids)))
> ids
# [1] 1 1 2 2 3
# Levels: 1 2 3

# use the levels to fetch columns and sum them
o <- sapply(as.numeric(levels(ids)), function(x) {
    rowSums(df[which(ids == x)])/df$length
})

> o
#          [,1]     [,2] [,3]
# [1,] 3.000000 7.000000    1
# [2,] 2.500000 4.500000    1
# [3,] 2.333333 3.666667    1
# [4,] 2.250000 3.250000    1
# [5,] 2.200000 3.000000    1
```